# rdbms tables to couchdb database tables

Tags: couchdb, rdbms

We are creating a new web application and we intend to use CouchDB. The old web application is being rewritten and we are migrating from RDBMS to CouchDB.  I have a RDBMS schema with 10+ tables and I want to recreate the same in CouchDB. Which is better approach to do this in CouchDB?

Options

1. Create a new database in CouchDB for every table in my RDBMS schema
2. Create only one database in CouchDB and store all RDBMS tables into this CouchDB, having an explicit column called doc_type/table_type to represent which table/row type it represents in RDBMS table.

What are the pros and cons of these approaches? What is the recommended approach?

Comment: It's not possible to provide a solid answer to your question(s).  FWIW I've always used document types, often projected as views, with great success - but mileage varies according to the problem domain.  I recommend reading up regarding the differences between relational and document data models e.g. [Moving from SQL Server to Couchbase](https://blog.couchbase.com/moving-from-sql-server-to-couchbase-part-1-data-modeling/) and [View Cookbook for SQL Jockeys](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/nosql.html#view-cookbook-for-sql-jockeys) as a start.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends.

In general, be wary of trying to "translate" a RDBMS schema naively to CouchDB -- it rarely ends up in a happy place. A relational schema -- if designed well -- will be normalized and reliant on multi-tabular joins to retrieve data. In CouchDB, your data model will (probably) not be normalized nearly as much, and instead the document unit representing either a row from a table, or a row returned from a joins in the relational DB.

In CouchDB there are no joins, and no atomic transactions above the document unit. When designing a data model for CouchDB, consider how data is accessed and changed. Things you need to be accessed atomically belong in the same document.

As to the many databases vs a single database with documents with a "type" field, the single database option allows you to easily perform map-reduce queries across your whole data set. This isn't possible if you use multiple databases, as a map-reduce view is strictly per-database. The number of databases should be dictated by the access pattern -- if you have data that is only ever accessed by a subset of your application's queries, and never needs slicing and dicing with other data, that can be housed in a separate database.

I'd also recommend checking out the new partitioned database facility in [CouchDB](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/master/partitioned-dbs/index.html) and Cloudant.

Comment: Though not a join in SQL parlance, CouchDB does support document joins [Joins With Views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/joins.html#linked-documents) which provides utility when linking documents.

Comment: I often hear that you shouldn't map relational to nosql databases, however, I think that it's not entirely fair and correct. I have migrated several big complex relational databases to nosql databases. No, you should not map every separate table to a single document, you will need to "flatten" the hierarchies on several logical groups of tables, and you have to keep your wits about when doing this. My databases were all pretty happy afterwards. However, YMMV, CouchDB has no concept of tables/collections it seems, except for separate databases, my organized RDBMS brain does not like that.